# Mongoose model.pre('save'), isModified, bcrypt

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I wonder how code below works. It seems to me that in given code isModified method compare clearText and hashedPassword so it should always return true

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
});

userSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  try {
      if (!this.isModified("password")) {
        return next();
      }
      let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
      this.password = hashedPassword;
      return next();
  } catch (err) {
      return next(err);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isModified` will only return true if you are changing the password.

So this will be triggered if the user does a password reset/change or they are setting it for the first time.

It will not be triggered for example if the user's name is changed.

You can read more about `isModified` here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified